# How to set Property Changed Event for a Particular Property of an Object in Collection

Tags: c#, events, inotifypropertychanged, c#-5.0

I have an ObservableCollection which has objects.
My requirement is I want to set Property Changed For a particular Property to trigger Collection Changed event.

I can set Property changed for the object like:

```
foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged prop in _baseColl)
{
 prop .PropertyChanged += prop_PropertyChanged;
}

prop_PropertyChanged()
{
//Will Refresh My Collection.
}
```

This case It will be called for all the properties in that Object.But i dont want that.

P.S : I also Know that we can trigger the CollectionChanged By "Add","Remove","Move" etc..But i want another solution in my case.

Answer (score 2):

All you can do if you're handling `PropertyChanged` is to check the "PropertyName";

```
prop_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "TheProperty")
    {
        //Will Refresh My Collection.
    }
}
```

This should be fine for most cases.  If you want a more narrowly-targeted invocation, then you can always consider using a custom event -- have the source object raise that event only when the property you are interested in changes.